# Asynchronous problem when dispatch the hook with Context API

Tags: react-native, react-context

I have my store using the Context API to create a user, where there are two screens for completing the registration.
The first screen has several input fields that I control with React Hook Form, and when I enter all the data, I navigate to the other screen and fill in 2 more inputs, one being a checkbox with several options.

On the first screen, I can get all the information from the user, and on the second screen, I can get only the values ​​of the checked boxes, and the location input that I have, it cannot insert into the state of my Context API.

### src/store/CreatePersonalAccount/index.tsx

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import { reducer } from './reducer'

export const initialState: PersonalAccount = {
  avatar: '',
  name: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  location: '',
  occupationCategory: '',
  occupationSubcategories: []
}

export const CreatePersonalAccountContext = createContext<
  IContext<PersonalAccount>
>({
  state: initialState,
  dispatch: () => {}
})

export const CreatePersonalAccountContextProvider: React.FC = ({
  children
}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  return (
    <CreatePersonalAccountContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </CreatePersonalAccountContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

### CreatePersonalAccount/action.ts

```
export enum CreatePersonalAccountActions {
  SET_CREATE_PERSONAL_ACCOUNT = 'SET_CREATE_PERSONAL_ACCOUNT',
}

export const setPersonalAccount = (payload: Partial<PersonalAccount>) => {
  return {
    type: CreatePersonalAccountActions.SET_CREATE_PERSONAL_ACCOUNT,
    payload
  }
}
```

### CreatePersonalAccount/reducer.ts

```
import { initialState } from './index'
import { CreatePersonalAccountActions as ActionTypes } from './action'

export const reducer = (state: PersonalAccount, action: IAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.SET_CREATE_PERSONAL_ACCOUNT:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload
      }
    case ActionTypes.RESET:
      return {
        ...initialState
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In my user creation routes, I have hooks that can be used both on the first screen and on the second screen.

```
import { useContext } from 'react'

import { CreatePersonalAccountContext } from 'store/CreatePersonalAccount'
import {
  setPersonalAccount,
  resetPersonalAccount
} from 'store/CreatePersonalAccount/action'

export function usePersonalAccount() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(CreatePersonalAccountContext)

  const setPersonalInformation = (state: PersonalAccountInformation) =>
    dispatch(setPersonalAccount(state))

  const setPersonalLocation = (location: string) =>
    dispatch(setPersonalAccount({ location }))

  const setPersonalOccupation = (
    params: Partial<
      Pick<PersonalAccount, 'occupationCategory' | 'occupationSubcategories'>
    >
  ) => dispatch(setPersonalAccount(params))

  const clearPersonalAccount = () => dispatch(resetPersonalAccount())

  const submit = () => {
    console.log('Enviar pra API', state)
  }

  return {
    state,
    submit,
    setPersonalLocation,
    clearPersonalAccount,
    setPersonalOccupation,
    setPersonalInformation
  }
}
```

The `setPersonalInformation` function is used on the first screen with the user information, and the other functions `setPersonalLocation` and `setPersonalOccupation` are used on the second screen of the user information, the problem is the `setPersonalLocation` function that cannot update the state with the new `location` property.

This function below is the function I use in the first info screen, and it works correctly, updating the `avatar`, `name`, `document`, `email`, `password` fields.

### SignUp/PersonalAccount/PersonalInformation/index.tsx

```
...
function handleRegisterPersonal(data: PersonalAccountInformation) {
    const personalInformationData = {
        ...data,
        avatar: image
    }
    setPersonalInformation(personalInformationData)
    navigation.navigate('PersonalLocationAndOccupation')
}
...
```

And on the screen where I would like to update the location property is the function below.

### SignUp/PersonalAccount/PersonalLocationAndOccupation

```
function registerPersonalAccountForm({ location }: PersonalAccountLocation) {
    setPersonalLocation(location)
    navigation.navigate('Welcome')
  }
```

And my final state is this, but without the location property assigned

```json
Object {
  "avatar": "file:///Users/vagnerwentz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BCB82E0B-A81E-495A-9917-80C315CEE735/data/Containers/Data/Application/FB8A6B2E-3F8F-4EBE-9AC0-128BBC80A84E/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FPlugApp0800-fe3f8358-2821-44a3-a206-d0e1909b03e0/ImagePicker/FF615EB9-E385-4397-9198-E49FE6CD8CE4.jpg",
  "documentation": "1234567890",
  "email": "email@email.com",
  "location": "",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "occupationCategory": "Developer",
  "occupationSubcategories": Array [
    Object {
      "id": "frontend",
      "title": "Front-end",
    },
    Object {
      "id": "backend",
      "title": "Back-end",
    },
  ],
  "password": "1234567890",
}
```

I've already tried to put it in the property inside the useForm, assign the context field, with my Context, but without success, I also tried to put a setTimeout to simulate an asynchronous call, and I didn't succeed either.

Comment: Are you sure the form field is correctly capturing the location provided? What does registration of the location form field look like?

Comment: @morganney Yeah I console.log the location property inside the function and appears the log. 

const setPersonalLocation = (location: string) => { 

    console.log('Location', location)
    dispatch(setPersonalAccount({ location }))
  }

`Location Xcxcxcxc`